# Get active document when changed in Visual Studio extension

Tags: visual-studio

So I'm currently writing an extension for VS using their extensibility API, and I've run into a bit of a snag. I need some kind of event (or other solution) that triggers when you tab between files, and when that happens I need to get the path to the new active document.

The problem is everything in the API that I have tried either fires at the wrong time, or when it is called, the current active document hasn't been updated yet so when I get the path it's still the file I just tabbed out of.

I've tried implementing the IVsRunningDocTableEvents interface, I've tried using the Events.WindowEvents.WindowActivated event, nothing so far has worked correctly.

```cs
EditorClassifier1Provider.myEnvDTE.DTE.Events.WindowEvents.WindowActivated += WindowEvents_WindowActivated;
```

```cs
class RdtEvents : IVsRunningDocTableEvents
    {
        public RdtEvents()
        {
            ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
            var rdt = (IVsRunningDocumentTable)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(IVsRunningDocumentTable));
            rdt.AdviseRunningDocTableEvents(this, out _);
        }

        int IVsRunningDocTableEvents.OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(uint docCookie, int fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame)
        {
            OpenConnectionCommand.docView = VS.Documents.GetActiveDocumentViewAsync().Result;
            Message.Send(null, null);
            OpenConnectionCommand.docView.Document.DirtyStateChanged += (s,e) => Message.Send();
            OpenConnectionCommand.docView.TextView.Selection.SelectionChanged += (s,e) => Message.Send();
            return Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

       //...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the method your looking for

```
    public int OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(
        uint docCookie,
        int fFirstShow,
        IVsWindowFrame pFrame)
    {

    }
```